# Add contact to Infusionsoft API with tags field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails framework. I want to add tag along with contact but its giving me error of "[NoFieldFound]No field found: Contact.Tags2". I am using following code:

```
    Infusionsoft.contact_add({:FirstName => 'Amy', :LastName => 'Smith', :Email => 'amysmith@gmail.com', :Tags2 => 244})
```

Can anyone please help me? How can we add tags along with contacts?

Comment: WHat's your model or the contact?

Answer (score 2):

Preet, to add tags to a contact in Infusionsoft, you first need to add the contact, and then add the contact to a group (i.e. apply a tag)

In Ruby, you'd run:

```
Infusionsoft.contact_add_to_group(contact_id, group_id)
```

contact_id is the ID of the contact you created.
group_id is the ID of the tag you want to apply, 244 in your example.

So to add a contact and then apply a tag, you'd run something like this:

```
contact_id = Infusionsoft.contact_add({:FirstName => 'Amy', :LastName => 'Smith', :Email => 'amysmith@gmail.com'})
Infusionsoft.contact_add_to_group(contact_id, 244)
```